# innerHTML not showing up when added input element dynamically

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am trying to add an `<input>` element using Javascript. However, the innerHTML is not showing up. Below is my code:

```
function addElements()
{
    container = document.getElementById("duration"); //a div container
    var input1 = document.createElement("input");
    var input2 = document.createElement("input");
    input1.type = "number";
    input1.min = "0";
    input1.max = "10";
    input1.required = true;
    input1.innerHTML = "years";
    input2.type = "number";
    input2.min = "0";   
    input2.max = "12";
    input2.required = true;
    input2.innerHTML = "months";
    container.appendChild(input1);
    container.appendChild(input2);
}
```

The result of this code only produces two number input fields without the innerHTML. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Inputs have no content.

Comment: can we give the input type after appeding a new element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you try to achieve is **[label][input]** in this case you have to add 2 new more elements on page.

```js
function addElements()
{
    container = document.getElementById("duration"); //a div container
    var label1 = document.createElement("label");
    var input1 = document.createElement("input");
    
    var label2 = document.createElement("label");
    var input2 = document.createElement("input");
    
    input1.type = "number";
    input1.min = "0";
    input1.max = "10";
    input1.required = true;
  
    label1.innerHTML = "years";
  
    input2.type = "number";
    input2.min = "0";   
    input2.max = "12";
    input2.required = true;
  
    label2.innerHTML = "months";
    
    container.appendChild(label1);
    container.appendChild(input1);
    container.appendChild(label2);
    container.appendChild(input2);
}

addElements();
```

```html
<div id="duration" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Input elements don't have inner content you can set with `innerHTML`. Instead set `value` property:

```
input1.value = "years";
```

However, it seems that in your case you want to set `placeholder`:

```
input1.setAttribute("placeholder", "years");
```

or you can set corresponding property as well:

```
input1.placeholder = "years";
```

Comment: But they are number inputs. The value can't be "years".

Comment: I think you're trying to do an HTML5 placeholder? set the placeholder attribute to "years"

Comment: I recommend always using `.setAttribute`

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. However, I am not trying to create a placeholder.

Comment: @jl90 Then you need too set a `value`.

Comment: @jl90, then you need to explain what you're trying to do because you defined something as allowing only 0-10 and provide an example of trying to set it to "years." Since an input tag has no innerHTML, I'm not sure what you're goal is unless you provide more detail.